# access result set of jdbcbatchitemwriter spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I am trying to read an excel sheet using itemreader and pass it to writer where i need to query for record existence. I am not sure how to access result set of jdbcbatchitemwriter so that i can validate whether query results. can any one please guide

Answer (score -1):

It can actually be done in `ItemProcessor`. To filter a record, one simply returns "null" from the ItemProcessor.(Ref : [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#filiteringRecords))

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369676/processing-batch-of-records-using-spring-batch-before-writing-to-db) post explains how to drop the duplicates in `ItemProcessor`. As per this example, you can maintain the list of `previousItems` from database to drop out the records.